# How to generate multiple jar files with gradle's java plugin

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a multi-project gradle build using the java plugin setup as follows:

```
myProj/
  settings.gradle
  build.gradle
  util/
    build.gradle
```

In my util project, I would like to generate 2 jars... one for packageA and one for packageB. I'm a noob with gradle so any help here would be much appreciated. Here are my settings and gradle files:

**myProj/settings.gradle**

```
include 'util'
```

**myProj/build.gradle**

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    repositories {
        maven {
            url "http://mymavenurl"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir 'src/java'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**myProj/util/build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    .
    .
    .
}
jar {
    baseName = 'packageA'
    includes = ['com/mycomp/packageA']
}
task packageBJar(type: Jar) {
    dependsOn classes
    includes = ['com/mycomp/packageB']
    baseName = 'packageB'
}
```

When I try to build my project here is the output:

```
:util:compileJava
:util:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:util:classes
:util:jar
:util:assemble
:util:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:util:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:util:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:util:test
:util:check
:util:build
```

I would hope to see :util:packageBJar after classes, but I'm not having any luck.

Comment: So your question is how to make it so that `packageBJar` gets run when you type `gradle build`, rather than `gradle packageBJar`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to declare `packageBJar` as an artifact of, say, the `archives` configuration:

```
artifacts {
    archives packageBJar
}
```

Now `gradle assemble`, and therefore also `gradle build`, will produce `packageBJar`.

Comment: Hi how can we make this work for `gradle install` which will fail when trying to install the jar produced with `packageBJar`